# Logistic Regression: math domain error - sigmoid function give value 1

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression, sigmoid

I'm trying out logistic regression. While running the code, i get math domain error in python. Found out that i'm inputting (mx+b > 38) values large than 38 into the sigmoid function and it outputs 1, and the log function (-log(1-1)) spits out "math domain error".

Here are my steps:

1. Find mx+b
2. input mx+b as x in the sigmoid function
3. Input the value from sigmoid, y-value, x-value to the cost function
4. Find gradient from the above values.
5. Optimize the weights using gradient value.

Please help.

[image: Error pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should normalize your data before putting it into logistic function. Normalization means putting values in [0, 1] range, therefore you should not be getting 1's as outputs from sigmoid anymore. You can use this function for normalization: [sklearn.preprocessing.normalize](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html)

Comment: By the way, do you think the above mentioned steps to approach logistic regression is correct ?

Comment: Seems like a correct approach, but I am definitely not an expert on this subject